# Конфигурация Виртуального Выделенного Сервера

Tags: java, веб-программирование, vps

Здравствуйте!

Мы с командой java - devы, и сейчас пилим свой веб - проект. Для его запуска нам понадобился VPS. На данный момент, он у нас появился, но как с ним работать - не знает никто.

Подскажите пожалуйста, как правильно установить (?), сконфигурировать и запустить такой сервер. Чем подробнее - тем лучше =)

П.С. Извините, если терминология не правильная, но встречаюсь с такой задачей впервые.

Comment: Вы заказали VPS, но не знаете, зачем он вам нужен? Если это не так, то, наверное, стоит указать, что именно у вас не получается на сервере развернуть.

Comment: Не совсем так. Мы знаем, зачем он нам нужен, но не знаем, как его настроить.
"стоит указать, что именно у вас не получается на сервере развернуть" - я не знаю, с чего вообще начать, так как никто из нас не имеет даже базового опыта в работе с VPS. 
А нужен он для работы веб-приложения, написанного на java , построенного на rest - архитектуре, DB = MariaDB

Comment: Лучше наймите админа (DEVops) - он вам всё сделает. Еще и инструкцию напишет.

Comment: Смешная шутка :)

Comment: Плакать потом будешь, когда сольют данные с криво настроенной VPS. 1 раз лучше закажи с инструкцией и консультацией (если сам ничего не понимаешь вообще) - потом делай сам. Дешевле выйдет.

Comment: Кто плакать будет? Я точно не буду, я умею настраивать сервера. А вот автор вопроса - будет плакать в любом случае. Потому что найти хорошего админа не разбираясь в администрировании - невозможно.

Comment: есть же фриланс с отзывами, рейтингами и т.п.

Comment: Ха-ха. Говорю же, смешная шутка.

Comment: Если автор вопроса обратится к фрилансеру - то через неделю на этом сайте появится вопрос - *"У нас есть **Настроенный Виртуальный Сервер**. Что с ним теперь делать?"*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Составьте список ПО, которое вам нужно на сервере
2. Узнайте у хостера как подключиться к серверу (обычно через ssh подключаются)
3. Узнайте какой дистрибутив стоит на сервере. И вообще какая там ОС.

Шаги выше можно выполнять параллельно

4. Для каждого ПО из списка гуглите `(название) (дистрибутив) install` и делаете что сказано.
5. Если все сделано правильно - сервер готов к использованию.

---

Будут конкретные проблемы - гуглите их. Или задавайте конкретные вопросы тут (не забыв проверить что такой вопрос не был задан ранее).

Comment: У меня есть IP, адрес, root под линукс и пароль. Если я правильно понимаю, SSH здесь не нужен?

А как понять, какое именно ПО (кроме линукс) мне нужно?

Comment: @АнтонЦуркану вы можете зайти на сервер как админ и поставить программу? Если нет - значит, ваш нужен ssh :)

Comment: @АнтонЦуркану что же до ПО - это только вы можете знать, что использует **ваша программа**

Comment: Я знаю, на чём она работает и из чего состоит: Java, Spring, Hibernate, Angular 2, Thymeleaf, Maria DB.

Comment: @АнтонЦуркану уберите из вашего списка библиотеки (они являются частью программы, а не используются ею) и добавьте веб-сервер

Comment: (если только ваша программа не случает HTTP-запросы напрямую)

Answer (score -2):

Ставьте Nginx для слушания 80 порта и перенаправляйте на внутренние порты, которые слушают ваши веб-сервисы (Spring/Play/VertX). Веб-свервисы запускайте в Docker-контейнерах и/или настройте Continuous Integration сервер (Например, TeamCity), чтобы автоматически деплоить приложения. В тяжелом варианте можно использовать Tomcat. Более подробно без конкретики не ответить.

Comment: запускать сервисы в CI? чего?

Comment: Я разве писал про запуск в CI? Я имел ввиду ручная дистрибуция через контейнеры или автоматический деплой через CI. Не нужно минусовать не подумав головой.

Comment: Tomcat намного тяжелее в настройке?

Comment: Если не нужны сложные сценарии, то Tomcat почти из коробки заработает, но он по сути управляет сервлетами, а не отдельными приложениями, поэтому если отдельные сервисы требуют разного окружения (разные базы, переменные окружения и т.д.), то их разделение по отдельным ресурсам придется делать в ручном режиме. Также же он не заменит собой CI - это разные вещи.

Comment: @VictorKhovanskiy да